# Issue running Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord, discord-interactions

I have made a discord bot in the past and had no issues, but I wanted to try and create a new bot utilizing the slash commands.

I wrote this code:

```
import interactions
import discord

bot = interactions.Client(token="Tokenhehe")

@bot.command(
    name="Action",
    description="Number between one and nine",
    scope=GUILDID,
)
async def my_first_command(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    await ctx.send("Hi there!")

@bot.command(
    name="Other",
    description="Set Destination or Item target",
    scope=GUILDID,
)
async def my_first_command(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    await ctx.send("Hi there!")

@bot.command(
        name="Player",
        description="Set a Player target",
        scope=GUILDID,
    )
async def my_first_command(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    await ctx.send("Hi there!")

@bot.command(
        name="Printout",
        description="Fetch most recent printout",
        scope=GUILDID,
    )
async def my_first_command(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    await ctx.send("Hi there!")
```

When I try to run it using F5 from atom, I get this response:

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000127036143D0>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000012703ABD1C0>, 344.703)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x0000012703614B80>

Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 0.693 s
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I feel like I am forgetting something simple, what could it be?

Comment: you create `bot` but you don't start it. Where is `bot.run()`? And what is `interactions` ?

Comment: I found out what is `interactions` and see its [documentation](https://interactionspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#running-the-bot-and-creating-commands) - it always usse `bot.start()` at the end.

Comment: better don't use the same name `my_first_command` for all commands because last `my_first_command` may replace all commands.

Comment: It looks like you're not using discord.py. Please add the proper tag. Here are a few examples on how to use slash commands on discord.py: https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what exactly was the solution, but I tried three things that seemed to have fixed it:

1. I added bot.start() to the end

```
bot.start ()
```

2. I changed the commands to:

```
async def second_command(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
```

3. I changed the names of all of the commands and descriptions to all lowercase:

```
@bot.command(
        name="player",
        description="set a player target",
```